# Windows shell script loop

Tags: windows, shell, loops

i want the script to ping IP , 
if the ip reached run speciffic program
else wait 5 min then try again ping the ip

this the code i wrote ,but it need some adjustment

```
@ECHO OFF

ping 192.168.1.5 

IF ERRORLEVEL   0 GOTO Label0
IF ERRORLEVEL   1 GOTO Label1


:Label0
%WinDir%\program.exe
GOTO End


:Label1
timeout /t 300
GOTO End
```

Comment: What happens when you run this ? What doesn't work ?

Comment: my problem is to make the script to execute from beginning  after the delay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

:loop    
    ping -n 1 -4 192.168.1.5 2>nul | find "TTL=" >nul 
    if errorlevel 1 (
        timeout /t 300
        goto loop
    )

    start "" "%WinDir%\program.exe"

    endlocal
    exit /b
```

- In IPv4, windows ping command will set errorlevel if any of the sent packets was lost, but if you ping a machine your same subnet, you get no packet lost, just an unreachable destiny. So, errorlevel is not the best option to check. It is better to look for the "TTL=" text in the output of the command.
- Error levels should be checked from high to low values. The construct `if errorlevel x` will be true for any errorlevel value greater or equal to `x`. So, `if errorlevel 0` will be always true.
- To return to previous point in code, at least you need a label to jump to it.